# python 2.7 windows 7 installing mysqllib mingw32

Tags: python

setup.py install build --compiler=mingw32

> > gcc: error /Z1: No such file or directory
> >
> > error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

## Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: if by "mysqllib" you mean mysqldb, here are windows binary installers http://www.codegood.com/archives/129

Answer (score -1):

After installing mingw32 compiler you'll need to set the PATH Windows environment variable to include the directory of the mingw/bin so it can find the gcc executable.  Note that you'll have to open a new cmd window to pick up the new PATH setting.

Comment: This is not the answer to the question. If the gcc path has not been set there would be no such line as `gc: error` etc.